# Parentfont seems to change randomly

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a weird situation here. The ParentFont property of newly-added components keeps changing to FALSE, within the IDE.

I can demonstrate it as follows:

1. File|New VCL Forms Application. No need to save anything.
2. Add 3 tLabels to the new empty form.
3. In turn, look at each one in the Object Inspector. The ParentFont is set to FALSE - it should be true.
4. Change each of the labels to ParentFont = TRUE.
5. Change the font size of the form, several times, and confirm that the labels change as expected.
6. Select one label, check its ParentFont in the Object Inspector. It's FALSE again!
7. Change the font size of the form again, and note that the last-inspected label doesn't change.

To me this is consistent with the label's font somehow being changed upon being selected in the IDE, however I can not detect this.

Does anyone have an idea what might be broken? And/or what I can do about it?

=========== [EDIT] ==============

Well, I have uninstalled and done a clean install of Delphi, with no 3rd party components. The problem is still evident!

Here's a video to demonstrate:
http://topshare.com.au/DelphiParentfontProblemDemo.avi

Comment: i've had similar problem before (XE5, Win8. not excatly same problem). It was caused by too many additional component installed. Have you try to restar delphi or PC? Maybe full clean reinstall delphi?

Comment: I'm hoping to avoid the full reinstall, that does take me a while. A clean IDE, using the -rTest option on startup, behaves a little differently but the problem is still there. I hesitate to try the Repair option as I'm uncertain whether it affects my addon components.

Comment: Is the Vcl.Forms.pas file unmodified?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's a known problem with XE5:
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=716297#716297